# If column values of two different table match then add value

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables  A and B in sql server 2008 . 
Id columns exists in both the tables
Table A has a new column Result
The question is for all the values of ID column in table B that matches with the values of id column in table A ,then I should put a TRUE  else false in the result column of table A

Thanks in advance

Got the answer !! not sure about the performance if the table has a 10 million rows
Tried out myself and got the answer

Declare a temp table

declare @temp table 
(id int, result varchar)

insert into @temp select A1.id,A1.result from A A1 inner join B B1 on A1.id =B1.id

update @temp set result = true

Comment: It's better for you to post your own answer to your question than to edit the question to include an answer. It let's other user's see the result. Regarding your answer, it doesn't set anything to `false` and it doesn't update `A`. Did we misunderstand the question?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to run 2 queries as below to achieve what you are asking.

```
update A set A.result = true from tableA A, tableB B where A.Id = B.Id
update A set A.result = false from tableA A, tableB B where A.Id != B.Id
```

Comment: Updated the answer. I syntax that I gave earlier was for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @A as Table ( Id Int, Result Bit NULL );
declare @B as Table ( Id Int );
insert into @A ( Id ) values ( 1 ), ( 2 ), ( 4 ), ( 8 );
insert into @B ( Id ) values ( 1 ), ( 2 ), ( 3 ), ( 4 );
select * from @A;
select * from @B;
update A
  set Result = case when B.Id is NULL then 0 else 1 end
  from @A as A left outer join
    @B as B on B.Id = A.Id;
select * from @A;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Update tableA a 
set result = true 
where exists (select 1 from tableB b where a.id=b.id);

Update tableA a 
set result = false
where not exists (select 1 from tableB b where a.id=b.id);
```